# Unexplained behaviour with -1 indexing in Python array

Tags: python, list

I was trying to do some string manip when I found out this:

```
s = "hefehefe"

l = len(s)

s[:l] # Outputs `hefehefe`

s[l-1::-1] # Outputs `hefehefe`

s[-1] # Outputs 'h'

s[l-1:-1:-1] # Outputs empty ' '
```

Why is it that Python doesn't recognise the end of the iteration with -1 index when executing the last line? Is that a known behaviour of list indexing?

Comment: When you're going backwards, use `None` instead of `-1` as the ending index. And yes, it's known behavior.

Comment: `-1` refers to the last element, so you're going from `l` (i.e. the past-the-last element) to the last element.  There are no characters between the two, so the result is empty.

Comment: oh! pretty simple then! thanks!

Comment: @Rufflewind       Edited code snipet now. Thanks for this

Comment: Also, I'm pretty sure line 2 and line 3 are both wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of your assertions are simply false:  you say

```
s[l-1::-1] # Outputs `hefehefe`
s[-1] # Outputs 'h'
```

but anybody with a Python interactive interpreter and the ability to copy and paste can see:

```
>>> s[l-1::-1] # Outputs `hefehefe`
'efehefeh'
>>> s[-1] # Outputs 'h'
'e'
```

Please do not make plain, false assertions easily verifiable as such: it's **not** nice.